# Draw a Line in UIView between 2 image views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to draw line between to imageviews (like linking the images..) in UIView. I have used

```
CGContextRef context    = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0,0); //start at this point

CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 20, 20); //draw to this point

CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

But here, my context is null. I dono whether i have to import any framework or import any headers.  Any suggestion or sample will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where you have written this code?

Comment: You have to import the Quartz framework and write this in the header: `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`, but if you didn't import it, then you would get compiler errors, so that's probably not the problem.

Comment: I advise you reading this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847876/whats-the-best-approach-to-draw-lines-between-views

Comment: I have written this in ViewDidLoad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
 CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0); 
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 90, 90.0); 
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 120.0, 150.0);
 CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Answer (score 1):

The very easy way is use label with height 1.:)

```
UILabel *seperator=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 53, 233, 1)];
seperator.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

[loginView addSubview:seperator];
```

Comment: Thanks for your supports dude.. Here is my final code.. I have subclassed my UIView and drawRect method as follows..      CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 // Drawing lines with a white stroke color
 CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
 // Draw them with a 2.0 stroke width so they are a bit more visible.
 CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
    
 // Draw a single line from left to right
 CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 90, 90.0);
 CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 120.0, 150.0);
 CGContextStrokePath(context);

Comment: @user1402675:its depend to you. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image_signature.image.size);
[yourImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, yourImageView.image.size.width, yourImageView.image.size.height)]; 
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 2.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 20, 20);
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
[yourImageView setImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

...and "yourImageView" is an imageview where you will draw the line. I suggest you to draw the line on each upper imageview, at the very bottom, it's an option.

Comment: Sorry friends.. nothing worked for me.. I have written this code in ViewDidload.. All i need is to dre\aw a simple line between two image views.. I am not able to post the image..

Comment: dude, that code works like a charm: use one of your imageViews as "yourImageView", and execute that code just once, right after you have presented yourImageView on the screen.